# Show that $12n+5$ and $5n-2$ are relatively prime for all $n$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Show that $12n+5$ and $5n-2$ are relatively prime for all $n$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$)

I've seen similar questions on here, I tried following their answers and doing it myself, but it's not working out for me. I tried the Euclidean Algo a few times and it's never ending.
I'd be happy if someone could post the way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: This is false, e.g., if $n=20$, the $\gcd$ is $49$.

Comment: You have a **sign typo:** It should be $\,12n+5,\ 5n+2,\,$ or $\,12n-5,\ 5n-2\,$ in order for them to be relatively prime. The same methods in the linked dupes work for such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euclidean algorithm might not reach $0$, but it will help greatly:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
12n+5&5n-2\\
12n+5-2(5n-2)&5n-2\\
2n+9&5n-2\\
2n+9&5n-2-2(2n+9)\\
2n+9&n-20\\
2n+9-2(n-20)&n-20\\
49&n-20
\end{array}
$$
So basically, if $n-20$ has a factor of $7$, then $12n+5$ and $5n-2$ will both have a factor of $7$ (and similarly for a factor of $49$). For instance, for $n=-1$ we get
$$
12n+5=-7\\
5n-2=-7
$$

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It's a good answer.

Comment: Upvoted, I also have no idea why this got downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

$$(12n+5,5n-2)=(2n+9,5n-2)=(2n+9,n-20)=(n+29,n-20)=(n+29,49)$$

for $n=7t+6$ where $t\in Z$ both can divisible by 7. They are not relatively prime.

Comment: What if $n=20$?